# regual expression for extracting the number

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to extract amount of memory from table like that.

```
+---------------+
| product_name  |
+---------------+
| DIMM - 1GB    |
| 8MB Cache /NM |
| RAM - 32 MB   |
| DIMM - 256MB  |
+---------------+
```

Probably, there is product name can be another number, so I need extract the number near 'GB' or 'MB'. Need to use regexp_replace function. I've got problems with regular expression building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to capture the first occurence of consecutive digits in the string, then you can use `regexp_substr()` as follows:

```
regexp_substr(product_name, '\d+')
```

You can be more specific with `regexp_replace()`. The following expression captures sequences of digits followed by `MB` or `GB`:

```
regexp_replace(product_name, '(^|.*\D)(\d+)\s*[MG]B.*', '\2')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e455a0fccbc0419188191be5547da363)**:

```
PRODUCT_NAME  | REGEXP_SUBSTR(PRODUCT_NAME,'\D+') | REGEXP_REPLACE(PRODUCT_NAME,'(^|.*\D)(\D+)\S*[MG]B.*','\2')
:------------ | :-------------------------------- | :----------------------------------------------------------
DIMM - 1GB    | 1                                 | 1                                                          
8MB Cache /NM | 8                                 | 8                                                          
RAM - 32 MB   | 32                                | 32
```